# Can't use hibernate entity in foreach

Tags: java, hibernate, foreach

I'am beginner in hibernate and i have 1 error in my code,and i don't know how to solve it. Why i can't use my entity in foreach.[Error in foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO1FL.png)

This is BookEntity class that was create by idea.

hibernate-version 5.0.1;
java SDK version 10.0.1

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "book", schema = "library")
 public class BookEntity {

private boolean edit;
private long id;
private String name;
private long author;
private int publishYear;
private long publisherId;

public boolean isEdit(){return edit; }
public void setEdit(boolean edit){this.edit = edit;}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false, length = 20)
public long getAuthor() {return author; }
public void setAuthor(long author) {this.author = author;}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "publish_year", nullable = false)
public int getPublishYear() {
    return publishYear;
}
public void setPublishYear(int publishYear) {
    this.publishYear = publishYear;
}


@Basic
@Column(name = "publisher_id", nullable = false)
public long getPublisherId() {
    return publisherId;
}
public void setPublisherId(long publisherId) {
    this.publisherId = publisherId;
}

    }
```

I will be very grateful for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your not defining the `bookList` in the correct way.

If you have one of the following:

- `List bookList = new ArrayList();`
- `List<Object> bookList = new ArrayList<>();`

Change it to `List<BookEntity> booklist = new ArrayList<>();` and it shall work fine.

Comment: Or even better, use a Set instead of List.

Comment: Nice tip @kaba713 +1